# homogeneity of an equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, variational-analysis

I am a student studying Michael Struwe's Variational method book.
In this book, he said using the homogeneity of
$$-\Delta u+\lambda u=u|u|^{p-2},$$
a solution of problem $$\begin{array}{lcl}
-\Delta u+\lambda u=u|u|^{p-2} \mbox{ in } \Omega\\ u>0 \mbox{  in  } \Omega\\ u=0 \mbox{ on } \partial \Omega \end{array} $$
can be obtained by solving a constrained minimization problem for the functional
$$E(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega{|\nabla u|^2+\lambda|u|^2 dx}$$ on $H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, restricted to the set $$M=\{u\in H^{1,2}_0(\Omega);\int_\Omega {|u|^p dx}=1\}.$$

What I can't understand is, firstly, I couldn't get why this equation is homogeneous equation. I think if I multiply a constant to u, the left side of equation is homogeneity 1 and the right side is homogeneity p-1, so it doesn't fit.
The second question is, if I accept the equation is homogeneous, how that fact can be used in this process.
I got everything else like how to make such E(u) form, but because of these questions, I feel that I can't fully understand it.
Thank you for reading my question. If you know the reason, please help me!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this so take this with a grain of salt. I think it's precisely because of this mismatch of homogeneity that you mention: If we minimize the energy functional with respect to the constraint that gives the right hand side, then Lagrange multipliers will give you a solution to $$-\Delta v+ \lambda v = \mu v|v|^{p-1}.$$ Then, at least if $\mu\neq 0$ (which I'm sure comes up somewhere in the argument), then you can consider $u=\mu^{p-1}v$ to get rid of this parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I think I got it now. Maybe it means we will consider each ∫Ω|u|pdx=c for any fixed c cases and solve each minimization problem under this condition, but as you mentioned, this problem is independent of such c. Thank you so much for your help!!:)